# How to make a stacked bar chart by years with percent values? R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here my Data

```
print(data) 
A tibble: 12 x 3
   `Age Group` Percent  Year
   <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Adults         0.78  2017
 2 Youth          0.05  2017
 3 Children       0.17  2017
 4 Adults         0.76  2018
 5 Youth          0.07  2018
 6 Children       0.17  2018
 7 Adults         0.77  2019
 8 Youth          0.05  2019
 9 Children       0.18  2019
10 Adults         0.06  2020
11 Youth          0.76  2020
12 Children       0.17  2020
```

My goal is to make a stacked bar chart for each year, but I would like to have labels with the values but in the percentage format (ie 70%).

What do i need to do?

Comment: do you need `ggplot(df1, aes(x = Year, y = Percent, fill = `Age Group`)) + geom_col() + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `scales::percent`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(Year, y = Percent, fill = `Age Group`)) + 
   geom_col() +
   geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(Percent)),
      position  = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Age Group` = c("Adults", "Youth", "Children", 
"Adults", "Youth", "Children", "Adults", "Youth", "Children", 
"Adults", "Youth", "Children"), Percent = c(0.78, 0.05, 0.17, 
0.76, 0.07, 0.17, 0.77, 0.05, 0.18, 0.06, 0.76, 0.17), Year = c(2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```